# How to find a polynomial that passes through a set of points (not just $1$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

I am learning that polynomials come in this form after they are fully factored:

$f(x) = a(x+\text{root $1$})(x+\text{root $2$})(x+\text{root $n$}).$

At which point, problems say, "find a polynomial that passes through, say, $(1, 2)$. Easy, just plug in $1$ for $x$, and $2$ for $f(x)$, and solve for $a$.

But what if I have a set of points I need it to cross through?

Using an example, let's say I have $f(x) = a(x)(x-2)(x-4)$. I want this to be able to pass through the points $(1,2)$ AND $(3,-1)$?

It seems like every time I solve for a using $1$ point, I modify it to where it no longer satisfies the other point I want. It's almost like I have to solve $2$ equations at the same time? Is this possible?

Comment: There exists exactly one polynomial of $n$ degree (in some cases with less than $n$ degree) that passes through $(x_0,y_0),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ $n+1$ points. There are many ways to obtain this polynomial. The most intuitive one is solving the system of n+1 equations given by $a_n x_i ^n+\ldots+ a_1 x_i +a_0=y_i$, $i\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$. There are other methods that simplify this task a lot, like Lagrange's interpolation polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial , or Newton interpolation polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial (and many others).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that it if you have $n+1$ points $(x_0,y_0),$ $(x_1,y_1), \ldots,$
$(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}),$ where the $x_i$ values are all different,
there is one **and only one** polynomial of degree $n$ or less that passes through those $n+1$ points.

Now, obviously once you have found the unique polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ or less that passes through those given $n+1$ points, the same polynomial passes through a lot of other points as well. For any given $x,$ just compute $p(x)$, and the polynomial passes through $(x,p(x))$ as well.

So you **might** be able to put a polynomial of degree $n$ or less through $n+2$ points -- if the $n+2$nd point just happens to agree with the unique polynomial that goes through the first $n+1$ points.
That is, if $p$ is the unique polynomial of degree $n$ or less that goes through the first $n+1$ points, and someone says it also needs to go through another point that happens to be at $(x_{n+1}, p(x_{n+1}))$, then OK -- you already have a polynomial going through that point.
But if they demand that the polynomial go through $(x_{n+1}, p(x_{n+1}) + 1),$
it simply is not possible to do with only an $n$th-degree polynomial.
You will need at least an $(n+1)$-degree polynomial to satisfy that demand.

In the case where you are given $f(x)=ax(x−2)(x−4),$
you know that the polynomial goes through the points $(0,0),$ $(2,0),$ and $(4,0),$
because $x=0,$ $x=2,$ and $x=4$ are all places at which $f(x) = 0.$
So you've implicitly been told $3$ points your polynomial must go through.
If you are given a $4$th point at a different $x$ coordinate (not $0,$ $2,$ or $4$), that's OK -- we know we can always find a polynomial of degree $3$ through any $4$ points with all different $x$ coordinates.
We also know from the three points $(0,0),$ $(2,0),$ and $(4,0)$
that the formula must be of the form
$f(x)=ax(x−2)(x−4).$
But we can choose $a$ in order to make the polynomial go through that $4$th point.

If we're now given another point the polynomial has to pass through,
that's $5$ points in total for a polynomial that is only of degree $3.$
If you're lucky, the new point happens to be on the unique degree-$3$ polynomial through the first $4$ given points. Otherwise there is no solution.

If the problem is just to find "a polynomial" through all the given points
(the three zeros at $(0,0),$ $(2,0),$ and $(4,0)$ and two other points with different $x$ coordinates), then you can solve the problem with a polynomial of degree $4,$ since you have only $5$ points you need to fit.